# IndexSizeError caused when Fading in the sound on a Video Element using JS

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I'm getting the following error

music.js:31 Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to set the 'volume' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The volume provided (1) is outside the range [0, 1].

My code below is shown. I've included a remote mp3 file for the example to work when you run the snippet.

What I'm trying to figure out is I have a condition set which says when the volume gets to 1 then clear the interval and stop.

The volume provided (1) is outside the range [0, 1] does not make make sense to me as an error since the volume is 1.

Any suggestions?

```js
window.onload = function playSound() {
    var currentSound;
// I have a div called "page"
    var soundcv = window.document.body;
    // Set the point in playback that fadeout begins. This is for a 2 second fade out.

// This only works for one sound for simplicity's sake
    function playSound(sound) {

        if (currentSound == null) {
            var audio = window.document.createElement('video');
            audio.setAttribute('id','audio1');
            audio.src = sound;
            audio.id = 'video';
            soundcv.appendChild(audio);
            currentSound = audio;
        }
        currentSound.volume = 0;
        currentSound.play();

    }

// This isn't a real audio file URL - replace it with one of your own
    playSound('http://dl.last.fm/static/1458674990/114531092/eaba95c9c6e959558078b8f4eaab169211205de80b3e194238a5469e9a0c5c84/Somewhere+off+Jazz+Street+-+Collateral+Damage.mp3');

    function fadeIn() {
        if (currentSound.volume === 1) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            return;
        }
        currentSound.volume += 0.005;
    }
    var timer = setInterval(fadeIn, 200);


};
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:

You should fix it with by setting volume like that:

`currentSound.volume = Math.min(currentSound.volume + 0.005, 1);`

---

Because JS (and other languages) use IEEE 754 to store floating numbers, which is subject to [precision errors](http://floating-point-gui.de/).
Ex.: `0.1 + 0.2 === 0.30000000000000004`.

In your interval call you increment the current volume with `0.005`. When you are near 1, you will get `0.9950000000000008`.
The next iteration is: `0.9950000000000008 + 0.005 === 1.0000000000000007`.

Try: `for(var i = 0, a = 0; i < 200; i++){console.log(a += 0.005)}`

The problem here is the message of console, where 1 don't give the exponential part (`.0000000000000007`)

Answer (score 0):

**==For anyone that is seen  same error read this==**

You must get that error, HTML5 player volume can only be set between 0 to 1 [0,1].

To achieve something that run from 0 to 1 , let say you have a range input like below:

```
<input id="Volume" type="range" onmouseup="SetVolume(this.value)" min="0" max="10" step="1">

   function SetVolume(val){
    var newVolume=val / 10;
    // when is 1 it will give 0.1 and so on up to 0.9 
    //next push will be 1 and it stops.
    currentSound.volume=newVolume;
    });
```